# how to convert a <String, Float>Map toString method to a generic Number version

Tags: java, generics

I have a method to get the contents of the Map as a String, like this:

```
    public static String toStringStringFloatMap(Map<String, Float> stringFloatMap)
    {
        String entries = "";

        Iterator<Entry<String, Float>> it = stringFloatMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry<String, Float> pair = it.next();
            entries += pair.getKey() + "=" + pair.getValue() + "\n";
        }

        return entries;
    }
```

Now I am trying to convert it to a generic version for Integer, Short, Double, .... . I have replaced all Float with "? extends Number" but the ....entrySet().iterator(); statement causes compile error and tells me the following:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator<Map.Entry<String,capture#6-of ? extends Number>> to Iterator<Map.Entry<String,? extends Number>>
```

I don't know what that "captured#6-of ? extends Number" means. anyone can explain it for me?

**EDIT:**

As Andy points out that the `<?, ?>` may be the best.

But my question is still that why the iterator() line cannot pass the compiler?

```
    public static String toStringMapError(Map<?, ?> map)
    {
        String entries = "";

        Iterator<Entry<?, ?>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); <<<<<------- error lineeeeeee
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry<?, ?> pair = it.next();
            entries += pair.getKey() + "=" + pair.getValue() + "\n";
        }

        return entries;
    }
```

Comment: Seems fine here: http://ideone.com/08E8lH.  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The issue is when he tries to replace Float with a generic type that extends Number.

Comment: Why not include the actual code which is failing?

Comment: Make the "error lineeeeeee" type `Iterator<? extends Entry<?, ?>>`. Or, just stop trying to use an explicit iterator, and use an enhanced for loop.

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to constrain to subclasses of `Number`, declare a type variable, and use throughout:

```
public static <T extends Number> String toStringStringNumberMap(Map<String, T> stringFloatMap) {
    String entries = "";

    Iterator<Entry<String, T>> it = stringNumberMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry<String, T> pair = it.next();
        entries += pair.getKey() + "=" + pair.getValue() + "\n";
    }

    return entries;
}
```

But you could simply use `?` for both the key *and* value: there's nothing here that requires an instance of `String` or `Number` specifically: all you need is types implementing `toString()`, which means any subclass of `Object` is acceptable.

```
public static String toStringMap(Map<?, ?> map) { ... }
```

---

You can also use an enhanced for statement, which is neater than an explicit iterator; and you should always use a `StringBuilder` when accumulating strings in a loop, and avoid building unnecessary temporary strings:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  sb.append(entry.getKey());
  sb.append('=');
  sb.append(entry.getValue());
  sb.append('\n');
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: can you explain "But you could simply use ? for both the key and value: there's nothing here that requires an instance of String or Number specifically" more concisely sir??

Comment: @B'bekShakya which "last term" are you referring to?

Comment: All you require here is key and value types which have the `toString()` method, i.e. they are subclasses of `Object`; or, anything you can store as keys and values in a `Map`. So you can make it `Map<?, ?>`, then you can pass any `Map` you like.

Comment: @Grayson because you can't pass a `Map<String, Float>` to a method which requires a `Map<String, Number>`.

Comment: Possible addition: The final version of `toStringMap` could also be implemented neatly as a single stream operation: `map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue() + "\n").collect(joining());`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't replace `Float` with `? extends Number`, instead, define a generic type in your method and use it:

```
public static <T extends Number> String toStringStringFloatMap(Map<String, T> stringFloatMap)
    {
        String entries = "";

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, T>> it = stringFloatMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry<String, T> pair = it.next();
            entries += pair.getKey() + "=" + pair.getValue() + "\n";
        }

        return entries;
    }
```

Comment: @grayson - see andy's reply on other answer, it just wouldnt work with Number